# UPDATE с условием MySQL

Tags: mysql

Привет всем, можно ли в MySQL сделать UPDATE с условием? То есть если золота меньше 500, то этим юзерам добавить 1000 золота?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вообще читали про структуру запросов SQL? Вот Вам описание структуры [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp). Условие прописывается в секции [WHERE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)